# Antenna input impedance calculation

Tags: antenna, impedance

I am attempting to calculate an antenna's input impedance. I have been given this information:

A 50 Ω coaxial line is feeding the antenna a 150 MHz frequency. It has a dielectric constant of 2.25, with an outer conductor of 40 mm. The antenna and coaxial cable are not matched, therefore have a standing wave ratio of 2.7. The first voltage minimum occurs 0.42 m from the antenna.

This is what I have so far:
$$
\lambda = \frac{c}{f\sqrt{\epsilon_r}}=\frac{3\cdot 10^8}{150 \cdot 10^6\cdot\sqrt{2.25}}\approx 1.33\mathrm{~m}
$$

$$
Z_{in} = Z_{0} \frac{VSWR +1}{VSWR -1}e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}}
$$

$$
Z_{in} = 50 \frac{2.7 +1}{2.7 -1}e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{1.33}}
$$

$$
Z_{in} = 1.285 - 108.815i
$$

It just seems too straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Impedance can, of course be complex. and gamma, the reflection coefficient            (ZL-Z0)/(ZL+Z0)  can also be complex. But VSWR is a scaler = (1+abs(gamma))/(1-abs(gamma)). Therefore you cannot obtain complex impedance from VSWR. There are always two impedance magnitudes that will create the same VSWR, one above Z0 and one below. By telling you that the first minimum is not at the antenna, but some distance away they are telling you that the magnitude of the impedance is greater than Z0. So all you can do is solve for the higher magnitude.

In the above equations you are simply creating an angle that is one wavelength long, but there is no information about the actual length of the transmission line.

Comment: So i went a head and had another crack, using the first voltage minimum. Still a bit confused though.
$$
\beta = \frac{2\pi}{\theta} = 2\pi \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{2} \pi \approx 4.412rad/m.
$$
$$
\theta r = 2\beta d_{min(n)}-(2n-1)\pi rad = \frac{(2*3)}{2}*0.42-\pi = \frac{13}{50} \pi \approx 46.8
$$
$$
|\Gamma| = \frac{S-1}{S+1} = \frac{2.7-1}{2.7+1} = \frac{1.7}{3.7} = \frac{17}{37} \approx 0.459
$$ 
$$
Z_{in} = Z_0*\frac{(1 + |\Gamma|)}{(1 - |\Gamma|)} 
$$
$$
Z_{in} = Z_0 * \frac{(1 + 0.459e^{j46.8})}{(1 - 0.459e^{j46.8})} = 7.767 + j57.54.
$$